# Nestjs Docker returns connection refused when accessing microservice

Tags: docker, microservices, nestjs

I am trying to set up a microservice cluster with docker and Nestjs but every time I try to call a microservice it gives me back a connection refused.

```
version: "3.8"
services: 
  api:
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      context: .
    depends_on: 
      - postgres
      - microservice
    ports:
      - "8080:3000"
    environment:
      DATABASE_URL: postgres://user:password@postgres:5432/db
      NODE_ENV: development
      PORT: 3000
    networks:
      - local

  postgres:
    image: postgres:10.4
    ports:
      - "35000:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: user
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
      POSTGRES_DB: db
    networks:
      - local

  microservice:
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      context: ../microservice
    depends_on: 
      - postgres
    ports:
      - "8877:9000"
    environment:
      DATABASE_URL: postgres://user:password@postgres:5432/db
      NODE_ENV: development
    networks:
      - local

networks:
  local:
    driver: bridge
```

In my main application code I connect to the microservice through the following code:

```
constructor() {
    this.client = ClientProxyFactory.create({
      transport: Transport.TCP,
      options: {
        host: '127.0.0.1',
        port: 8877
      }
    })
  }
```

And in the microservice I use the following code to set it up:

```
const microserviceOptions = {
  transport: Transport.TCP,
  options: {
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    port: 8877
  }
}

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.createMicroservice(AppModule, microserviceOptions);
  app.listen(() => {
    logger.log('Microservice is listening ...');
  });
}
bootstrap();
```

However, when I perform a request my main container gives the following error back:

```
[Nest] 19 - 03/24/2021, 8:00:36 AM [ExceptionsHandler] connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8877 +329786ms

api_1 | Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8877

api_1 | at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1144:16)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I noticed two potential problems:

1. In case you main app runs in a container within the same network of your microservice, try to set the host to: `microservice` (the name of the service in the docker compose file) instead of `127.0.0.1` and the port to the internal ip of the microservice, in your case: `9000`
2. You are telling the microservice to listen on port 8877, i guess you need to listen to 9000 as your docker compose file suggests.

Comment: How does nest js know that microservice is a valid hostname? Does docker handle this automatically?

I changed it, and now it gives me the following error
There is no matching message handler defined in the remote service. +4624ms

Comment: What I was missing was the host. It worked when I added that